# Unable to find dmtx shared library

Tags: python-3.x, importerror, shared

I installed pylibdmtx. When I try to import this I get an error:

```
from pylibdmtx import pylibdmtx

ImportError: Unable to find dmtx shared library
```

I am using python 3.8.8 on mac.

Answer (score 0):

I installed it this way:

```
brew install libdmtx
```

problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to add path for dmtx library.

Check if dmtx is installed.

```
dmtxread --version
```

Find the location of dmtx (I installed the library using brew).

```
brew list dmtx-utils
```

or

```
find /opt/homebrew -name libdmtx\*
```

Now we need to locate the library location into ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc that is up the shell you are using. Insert a line of code into the file to point the location.

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH={your_dmtx_lib_location}:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Here is a full code of my .zshrc file

````
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/pete/miniconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/pete/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/pete/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/pete/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libdmtx/0.7.7/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<```
````